# Triggering videos using "onkeypress" in HTML however only last code within the script will trigger a video and unsure why

Tags: javascript, html, video, keypress

I am triggering videos using the "onkeypress" function assigning videos to keys which is working well however I am only able to trigger the last code in the script!

I'm pretty new to programming, and am having a hard time working out why it won't work. Both codes in the script work fine individually, but then when placed together, only the last one will work.

I'm attempting to make something like this: http://patatap.com/

Code below:

```js
var video1 = document.getElementById("clap-test");
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "83") {
    video1.currentTime = 0, video1.play();
  }
};

var video2 = document.getElementById("chord-1");
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "65") {
    video2.currentTime = 0, video2.play();
  }
};
```

```css
#backplate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -4;
}

#twinkle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -3;
  mix-blend-mode: screen
}

#skel-walk {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#clap-test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#chord-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<!--BACKPLATE-->
<img id="backplate" src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Back_Plate00000.png">

<!--SKEL-WALK-->
<video id="skel-walk" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_Skeleton_Walk_TTP.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--CLAP-TEST-->
<video id="clap-test" preload="auto">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--CHORD-2-->
<video id="chord-1" preload="auto">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Chord_2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--TWINKLE-->
<video id="twinkle" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Twinkle.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>
```

Comment: @rabbit guy Hi sorry my mistake, I thought it was part of java, ill remove the tag - new to all of this!! Have you any suggestions what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the line below your declaration of `video2`, you're **overwriting** the behaviour of `document.onkeypress`. Writing `document.onkeypress = function(e) {}` a second time overwrites the first function that you wrote for it.

You need to only use **one** `document.onkeypress` function, and run **both** conditionals inside of that one function (as follows):

```js
var video1 = document.getElementById("clap-test");
var video2 = document.getElementById("chord-1");
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "83") {
    video1.currentTime = 0, video1.play();
  }
  if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "65") {
    video2.currentTime = 0, video2.play();
  }
};
```

```css
#backplate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -4;
}

#twinkle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -3;
  mix-blend-mode: screen
}

#skel-walk {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#clap-test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#chord-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<!--BACKPLATE-->
<img id="backplate" src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Back_Plate00000.png">

<!--SKEL-WALK-->
<video id="skel-walk" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_Skeleton_Walk_TTP.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--CLAP-TEST-->
<video id="clap-test" preload="auto">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--CHORD-2-->
<video id="chord-1" preload="auto">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Chord_2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>

<!--TWINKLE-->
<video id="twinkle" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
  <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Twinkle.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
</video>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This sorted it out, I was going mad! Thanks again!! :D